# Android device forced to restart on app launch

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I changed a Splash image and it seem's every time I try to launch the application it restarts my phone.

I changed the image back but the same thing happens. I found an article mentioning something about if the Splash image size is too large this happens? But I downsized the image to an extremely small image with the same results.

Has anyone encountered this before?

SplashActivity code

```cs
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   try
     {
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
        Finish();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        Crashes.TrackError(ex);
     }
}
```

This is where the restart occurs.

Comment: its batter to post your code.

Comment: could you share your project ?(It can be a simple example of a problem that can be replicated)， i could not reproduce your issue on my side.

Comment: Try taking a picture with at-least around 72 Resolution so something around 3000 x 4000 I'd say Set that as your Android Splash, That seem's to cause this, I swapped out the image for one with a Resolution of 12 and that seem's to work but i'm going to just run some more tests today and then ill post more